# Hardcode value of a variable in function definition

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that is written on the client side, send to a server as a string, and executed there. 
Inside this function I use some, primitive, variable of the client. An example could be

```
function (obj){
   return obj.number == aNumber;
}
```

where `aNumber` is an integer variable on the client side, while `obj` is an object living on the server.

The problem is that being the function executed on the server, the server doesn't have any `aNumber` variable there, so what I would like to do is to replace `aNumber` with his actual value, but I don't know how to do that, since the code of the function is actually never executed on the client.

Is there any solution (that possibly doesn't involve parsing the function as String)?

It seems a trivial question but I couldn't find a solution at all.

Comment: You are sending arbitrary code to the server which it executes? I'd stop right there. Seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: I would use a template engine, like [underscore one](http://underscorejs.org/#template) by instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry my bad I correct.
deceze: yes it's terrible from security point of view, but bare with me for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Since `aNumber` only exists on the client, that's the only place you can do this.

You can do a substitution (on the client):

```
var functionString = theFunction.toString();
functionString = functionString.replace(/\baNumber\b/g, aNumber);
```

...and then send `functionString` to the server. That assumes this code is running in a context that has access to `aNumber`, as the function being turned into a string does; and that `aNumber` is really a number.

But this is a ***seriously*** bad idea. Stepping back from the details and looking at the broader picture, I'm *sure* there's a solution that doesn't involve sending a function to the server to be executed there.

Comment: There's, but right now I wanted just to test a few things and I thought this was the fastest way. It seems it wasn't after all.

Comment: @user1544128: Well, the above should let you do that, in a controlled environment. :-)

Comment: True, but the function are a bit more elaborated than that :)

Comment: @user1544128: Well, regex is probably going to be the way you deal with that. :-) Or of course, if this was just meant to be quick and easy and is turning out not to be, going another way entirely... Good luck!